# Full Html code not importing Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a webpage and when I get the page using the request.get(), I am not getting the whole html code some. When I execute the code there is an empty div tag in the body. I am not sure why it is happening. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib
import requests
r = requests.get("https://ethermine.org/miners/8153516Db85e201abD29A0FfCcd9cCeF4aFF33c6/dashboard")
data = r.text
print(data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
mydivs = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "card-body"})
h5 = mydivs.findChild()
span= h5.findChild()
print (span.text)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what information exactly you are trying to scrape?

Comment: If you go to the webpage, you can see the hashrate. that is what I want.

Comment: All of the information seems to be available with their api: https://ethermine.org/api/pool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In[2]: import requests
  ...: 
  ...: url = 'https://api.ethermine.org/miner/8153516Db85e201abD29A0FfCcd9cCeF4aFF33c6/dashboard'
  ...: r = requests.get(url)
  ...: r.raise_for_status()
  ...: data = r.json()
In[3]: data['data']['currentStatistics']
Out[3]: 
{'time': 1539117000,
 'lastSeen': 1539116966,
 'reportedHashrate': 764394781,
 'currentHashrate': 794166666.6666665,
 'validShares': 679,
 'invalidShares': 0,
 'staleShares': 55,
 'activeWorkers': 7,
 'unpaid': 196476273209661060}
```

Answer (score 2):

### The reason why you can't retrieve all the HTML

The reason why you don't get the full HTML is because when you send a GET request using the requests library, it doesn't trigger the javascript on the website you're attempting to scrape.

Here you can see what the page looks like without javascript triggered (completely empty):
[image]

If you use chrome, you can use the developer tool to view this for yourself. 
Right click -> inspect element -> network -> settings -> disable javascript

### A possible solution

Use [selenium webdriver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) or phantomJS if you do not want a visible driver.

Comment: Ok, I understand now